# Golang generics for xml generation

Tags: go, generics, polymorphism

I have to generate an `XML`, my current code is the following:

```golang
type ReportableSeller struct {
    Identity Identity `xml:"Identity"`
}

type Identity struct {
    EntitySeller     *EntitySeller     `xml:"EntitySeller,omitempty"`
    IndividualSeller *IndividualSeller `xml:"IndividualSeller,omitempty"`
}

type EntitySeller struct {
    Standard StandardEntSeller `xml:"Standard"`
}

type IndividualSeller struct {
    Standard StandardIndSeller `xml:"Standard"`
}

type StandardEntSeller struct {
    EntSellerID EntSellerID `xml:"EntSellerID"`
}

type StandardIndSeller struct {
    IndSellerID IndSellerID `xml:"IndSellerID"`
}

type EntSellerID struct {
}

type IndSellerID struct {
}
```

Using thiese types I simply add an `EntitySeller` of a `IndividualSeller` based if the `vat` is defined or not and the `omitempty` the correct `xml` is generated.

But I don't really like it, because I have to define the `Standard` twice and use those two nullable variales in Identity, instead of a mandatory one. The idea was to use generics.

Here are the structs so far:

```golang
type ReportableSeller struct {
    Identity Identity[here I need a sort of interface] `xml:"Identity"`
}

type Identity[T any] struct {
    Seller T
}

type EntitySeller struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name              `xml:"EntitySeller"`
    Standard Standard[EntSellerID]
}

type IndividualSeller struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name              `xml:"IndividualSeller"`
    Standard Standard[IndSellerID]
}

type Standard[T any] struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name   `xml:"Standard"`
    SellerID   T
}

type EntSellerID struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name   `xml:"EntSellerID"`
}

type IndSellerID struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name   `xml:"IndSellerID"`
}
```

The problem here is that the type of Identity in ReportableSeller wants a generic type:
`cannot use generic type Identity[T any] without instantiation`.

Is it possible to fix it?

In C# I would use inheritance and polimorphism...

**Edit:**

In the meanwhile I ended up with the following:

```golang
type Identity struct {
    Seller any
}
```

With that I can do what I need to, however, not relly typed and error safe.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand question correct, you have to simply add type parameter to the `ReportableSeller` like

```
type ReportableSeller[T any] struct {
    Identity Identity[T] `xml:"Identity"`
}
```

and `xml.Marshal` required instance

```golang
rs1 := ReportableSeller[IndividualSeller]{}
...
rs2 := ReportableSeller[EntitySeller]{}
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/ZdqKKlkqlUs)</kbd>

> Yes and no. If the ReportableSeller struct were the main item, I agree, but in my case it is nested: `type DPIBody struct { ReportableSeller []ReportableSeller "xml:"ReportableSeller"" }`

Try to implement [Marshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Marshaler) for the struct (`ReportableSeller`) and use one as the field of the `DPIBody`:

```
type DPIBody struct {
    ReportableSeller []xml.Marshaler `xml:"ReportableSeller"`
}

type ReportableSeller[T any] struct {
    Identity Identity[T] `xml:"Identity"`
}

func (rs ReportableSeller[T]) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    return e.EncodeElement(rs.Identity, start) // simple example
}
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/PJIQ5V7-90A)</kbd>

*Update*:

> What any you mean (where you need to type safety)? In Identity(Seller field) or DPIBody (ReportableSeller  field)?

> Everywhere, I would like to have type safety. Dont know if it is possible in GO.

Declaration an interface with *type constraint* (look at [Type Sets](https://go.dev/blog/intro-generics)) and using it for `ReportableSeller` and `Identity` structs limit the number of types used for ones:

```
type (
    Seller interface {
        IndividualSeller | EntitySeller
    }
)

type ReportableSeller[T Seller] struct {
    Identity Identity[T] `xml:"Identity"`
}

type Identity[T Seller] struct {
    Seller T
}
```

```golang
/*
  1️⃣ and 2️⃣ -> Compilation Error: "Type does not implement constraint 'Seller' because type is not included in type set ('IndividualSeller', 'EntitySeller')"
*/
rs := []any{
    ReportableSeller[IndividualSeller]{},
    ReportableSeller[EntitySeller]{},
    ReportableSeller[any]{}, // 1️⃣
    ReportableSeller[string]{}, // 2️⃣ 
}
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/Lj3mOmEMaEA)</kbd>

if the field `ReportableSeller` (slice) of `DPIBody` have to contains only one type of the `ReportableSeller[T]` (`ReportableSeller[IndividualSeller]` or `ReportableSeller[EntitySeller]`), it implements by the same way:

```golang
type DPIBody[T Seller] struct {
    ReportableSeller []ReportableSeller[T] `xml:"ReportableSeller"`
}
```

```golang
/*
  1️⃣,2️⃣,3️⃣ -> Compilation Error: "Cannot use 'ReportableSeller[?]{}' (type ReportableSeller[any]) as the type ReportableSeller[IndividualSeller]"
*/
dpi := DPIBody[IndividualSeller]{
    ReportableSeller: []ReportableSeller[IndividualSeller]{
        ReportableSeller[IndividualSeller]{},
        //ReportableSeller[EntitySeller]{}, // 1️⃣
        //ReportableSeller[any]{}, // 2️⃣
        //ReportableSeller[string]{}, // 3️⃣
    },
}
```

but if the field `ReportableSeller` (slice) of `DPIBody` has to contain any type of `ReportableSeller`, only way to use `[]any` or `[]xml.Marshaller`, as described above.

Comment: Yes and no. If the ReportableSeller struct were the main item, I agree, but in my case it is nested:

`type DPIBody struct { ReportableSeller []ReportableSeller "xml:"ReportableSeller"" }`

Comment: `ReportableSeller` can  implement `xml.Marshaler` and you can use `[]xml.Marshaler` as the field of the `DPIBody `

Comment: Yes, this could be the solution. However, there is still the `any`.

Comment: What `any` you mean (where you need to type safety)? In `Identity`(`Seller` field) or `DPIBody` (`ReportableSeller ` field)?

Comment: Everywhere, I would like to have type safety. Dont know if it is possible in GO.

Comment: @Emaborsa -> I think, you can try to use interface with type construction (look at updates).

Comment: Looks good. And what If I have an container struct with an array of Sellers like `type Body struct { ReportableSeller []ReportableSeller }`

Comment: It won't compile. You can't `Use of generic type without instantiation`.

Comment: I know, Is there a way to define an array of Sellers without using the any?

Comment: In your case,  only way use `any` or define an interface (or use exists as `xml.Marshaler`) for  `ReportableSeller` field.